# C# TCP/IP Client that sends data received from serial port - Suggestions

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, tcp, serial-port

Currently im working on an **app that receives data from RFID card reader throu serial port. The data, afterwards the data should be sent by TCP/IP to a server.**

I already have both thing working, but not at the same time. I can read ID from card, and i can also send some text to server. But i would like to ask you for suggestion, what would be the best solution for those two things working together.

At the moment i have TCP/IP usage and Serial usage in two classes. From main class im creating objects of both classes and starting a thread that reads data from serial port.

**Should i try something like this?**

In class i would create only serial usage object and call a thread that handles reading. Inside of that reading thread, i would call a new thread that would open TCP/IP connection and sent data that it has recieved from serial port.

Another somehow simlar approach would open both connections from main class, but it would start TCP/IP sending thread (throu already open connection) from serial port recieveing thread.

I dont have too much experience with threading, so thats why i ask for your help fellow software developers. Thanks! (if that would help, i could paste some parts of code here).

UPDATED:

Thats for the tip, i'll look closer into that what you suggested. I guess that is good idea, but as i said i dont have too much experience with threading. Would it work, if i would create separate threads in those classes, and they would both use same object, lets say object of class Message, i would create new object in a COM handling thread, and TCP/IP handling thread would use that object to send the data from it throu TCP/IP? Can i make a queue of objects of class Message just like i can do with List? Also, how do i pass that queue of objects created in one thread in class toanotherthread

Comment: See my blog post, [Simple multithreading, part 2](http://blog.mischel.com/2013/07/18/simple-multithreading-part-2/) for an example of using `BlockingCollection`. The sample reads and writes a file, but the concepts are the same: the input thread reads a file and queues the data. The output thread reads a queue of messages and writes to an output file. The sample has two queues because there's a processing step in the middle, but you could eliminate the processing step and use a single queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Abstracting the two different communication methods into separate classes is good design so I would stick with that.

Rather than handling threads in your main class, have each communications class deal with its own thread management and communicate between them via a shared [threadsafe queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx).

Your serial comms object can then deal with talking to the serial port, reading data and putting that data into the queue. The TCP comms object can deal with connections, reconnections, disconnections etc... and consuming data from the queue and sending it to the socket and sending it out on the network.

Your main class can just create the queue and the two comms objects passing in the same queue instance.

Comment: Thats for the tip, i'll look closer into that what you suggested. I guess that is good idea, but as i said i dont have too much experience with threading. Would it work, if i would create separate threads in those classes, and they would both use same object, lets say object of class Message, i would create new object in a COM handling thread, and TCP/IP handling thread would use that object to send the data from it throu TCP/IP? Can i make a queue of objects of class Message just like i can do with List? Also, how do i pass that queue of objects created in one thread in class toanotherthread

Comment: Good suggestion, but I'd suggest [BlockingCollection<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) rather than `ConcurrentCollection<T>`. The `BlockingCollection` has a much nicer API, handles cancellation and non-busy waits, etc. By default it uses a `ConcurrentQueue` as its backing store so you still get FIFO behavior.

Comment: @Lichoniespi Yes the collections are templated (<T>) so you can create a BlockingCollection<Message>. Don't instantiate it in a thread, instantiate it in your main class and pass it into the Serial and Network handling classes (through the constructor possibly?), then they will both use the same instance.

Comment: Great tip Richard. Thats exactly what im going to do. I'll let you know guys if i have any problems. brb coding...

Comment: Well, it works. More or less. I am able to add an object to my BlockingCollection in one thread, and read it in another. But i would like to also delete that object, after it has done its work. There will be many objects and it has to work like that Producer gets new object every few seconds -> Consumer reads the object every few seconds and sends it throu TCP/IP, if there is confirmation the object has been sent succesfully, i would liek to delete that object from BlockingCollection.

Comment: Ok, looks like i have achieved what i wanted. I am able to send objects from one place to another, by this BlockingCollection<T>. I have solved problem of removing items by using TryTake to read them and send throu TCP/IP. I think i can mark this question as solved. Great help guys, if someone would ever have same problem as me, they should read this thread. Thanks!